# Solve the equation system of 10 equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I need to solve the equation system

$x_1(x_1-1)=3x_2-2^2$
$x_2(x_2-1)=5x_3-3^2$
$x_3(x_3-1)=7x_4-4^2$
...
$x_9(x_9-1)=19x_{10}-10^2$
$x_{10}(x_{10}-1)=x_1-1^2$

I have generalized it to

$x_n(x_n-1)=(2n+1)x_{n+1}-(n+1)^2$

until I get to $x_{10}$. But then I don't know what to do...
EDIT: typo

Comment: Where did you get this system from? It is quadratic for each of its 10 equations, so I expect up to 1024 solutions.

Comment: No typo in the last expression, I'm afraid.The system is from one of the assignments from my university.

Comment: @user376343, Sorry, I looked at the wrong expression. You're right.

Comment: The generalized equation works for $n<10,$ but not for $10.$ If you know modular arithmetic, you'd rather write $(2n+1)mod(20)\cdot x_{(n+1)mod(10)} - \big((n+1)mod(10)\big)^2.$

Comment: @Harry I deleted the tag and added two others. If you do not agree, re-edit it.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Assume $x_i\in \mathbb{R},\;i=1,\dots,10.\;$ 
     Adding the $10$ equations and putting all terms to the left side gives
$$(x_1-1)^2+(x_2-2)^2+\cdots (x_{10}-10)^2=0,$$

which is only possible if ... (you can finish, I think).